# initializing firebase with credentials stored in s3

Tags: c#, firebase, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm using this c# code inside a lambda authorizer:

```
FirebaseApp.Create(new AppOptions()
            {
                Credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile("https://my-bucket.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/credentials.json"),
            });
```

I get this error:
Could not find a part of the path '/var/task/https:/my-bucket.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/credentials.json'

How can I store the file in /var/task?

Comment: you are trying to get `FromFile` but the link you gave is https....is there a diff method you can use for https?

Comment: There is FromJson but I don't want to put the json itself in the code...

Comment: use any https module, copy the file to `/tmp` on lambda, and then say `FromFile("/tmp/<fileName>")`. When interacting w/ S3, especially from lambda, you should look at the SDK for your runtime (C#)

Comment: That sounds good, but I think anyways using s3 would be slow if the function needs the file in every call. Just don't know how to put a file in /var/tasks..

Comment: you cannot touch `/var/tasks` with lambda...you would need to force your path to something else

Answer (score 0):

You should look into this [guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-envvars.html) on how to use environment variables in lambda. I think this approach would make more sense, than storing the credentials in S3.

Comment: I tried to put the url in an environment variable, I get the same error (it looks in /var/task)

Comment: Not the url, but the credentials itself.

Comment: I also tried that and it didn't work. I tried to put it in the FIREBASE_CONFIG variable and get this error: The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials